# Evaluate LaTeX parts conditionally depending on Lua state

Tags: luatex, conditionals

In LuaLaTeX, I want to evaluate parts of the document conditionally, depending on Lua state.

A way to evaluate parts conditionally in LaTeX is a `\if \else \fi` construct.
A simple approach to connect this to Lua would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand{\luaif}[1]{\ifnum1=\directlua{if #1 then tex.sprint(1) else tex.sprint(0) end} }

\directlua{a = 1}

\begin{document}
\luaif{a == 1} true \else false \fi % -> true
\luaif{a == 2} true \else false \fi % -> false
\end{document}
```

This feels quite hacky, though.

Are there any alternative (better) approaches, maybe already built-in?

Comment: I would not do `\luaif{a == 1} true \else false \fi % -> true` as that leaves umatched `\else` and `\fi` so can not be nested in any other `\if` construct,  eg `\iffalse \luaif{a == 1} true \else false \fi   \fi`  does not work

Comment: I agree with David. A better definition would be `\newcommand*{\luaif}[1]{\ifnum1=\directlua{tex.sprint((#1) and "1" or "0")}\expandafter\@firstoftwo\else\expandafter\@secondoftwo\fi}`. Then use it like `\luaif{<cond>}{<true>}{<false>}`.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle In LuaTeX there is a mechanism to make the nested construct work: `\iffalse \ifcondition\luaif{a == 1} true \else false \fi \fi`